# Cannot consume scoped service from singleton Windows Host Service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am writing windows service here is my Program.cs file:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
   
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddScoped<IEncryption, Encryption>();
                services.AddScoped<IInsertUser, InsertUser>();
                services.AddScoped<IParseCSVFile, ParseCSVFile>();
                services.AddDbContext<LoginContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Previdence")));
                
            }).UseWindowsService();
}
```

The error is

> {"Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: PrevidenceUserLoader.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'PrevidenceUserLoader.Utilities.IEncryption' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'."}

The only place I use the IEncryption service is injected into the this class:

```
 public class InsertUser : IInsertUser
{
    private readonly LoginContext _context;
    private readonly IEncryption _encryption;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public static List<string> EncryptedColumns = new List<string> { "SocialSecurityNumber", "CodeDisplay", "FirstName", "LastName", "MiddleName", "PreferredName", "LastNameInitial" };
    public static List<string> CapitalizeColumns = new List<string> { "FirstName", "LastName", "MiddleName", "PreferredName", "LastNameInitial" };

    private Subjects encryptedSubjects;
    
    public InsertPrevidenceUser(LoginContext context,  IEncryption encryption, IServiceScopeFactory scope)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scope;
        _context = _scopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LoginContext>();
        
        _encryption = encryption;
    }
    
    public InsertStatus InsertUsers(Subjects user)
    {
        InsertStatus status = new InsertStatus();
        
        
        if(user != null)
        {
                //validate each user record
                if (ValidateUser(user))
                {
                    //good to go, encrypt then save
                    var encryptUser = _encryption.EncryptSubjects(user, EncryptedColumns);
                    if(encryptUser != null)
                    {
                        _context.Subjects.Add(encryptUser); //save it
                        status.Message = "Insert Sucessful";
                        status.UserName = "Test";
                        return status;
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                //something puked, return the list of errors.
                    status.Message = "Record did not insert";
                    status.UserName = "test";
                    return status;

                }

        }
            return null;
    }

    private bool ValidateUser(Subjects ValidateSubject)
    {
        var encryptedFirstName = _encryption.Encrypt(ValidateSubject.FirstName);
        var encryptedLastName = _encryption.Encrypt(ValidateSubject.LastName);

        var firstname = ValidateSubject.FirstName;

        var foundSubject = _context.Subjects.Where(x => x.FirstName == encryptedFirstName && x.LastName == encryptedLastName).ToList();
        if(foundSubject.Count > 0)
        {
            //something was found, not good
            //add to messages (inserts, errors)
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then I removed the IServiceScopeFactory and reset the _context to context and the error then read:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: UserLoader.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'UserLoader.Utilities.IParseCSVFile' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)

And this is where I'm stuck.  Here is the ParseCSVFile code:

```
public class ParseCSVFile : IParseCSVFile
{
    public List<Subjects> ParseSubjectCSV(string inputFilePath)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputFilePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SubjectsMap>();
            csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
            csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Subjects>().ToList();
            return records;
        }
    }
}
```

And this file is called from the Worker:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
   
    private readonly IParseCSVFile _parse;
    private readonly IInsertPrevidenceUser _insert;
   
    
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IParseCSVFile parse, IInsertPrevidenceUser insert)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        Configuration = configuration;
        _parse = parse;
        _insert = insert;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //_logger.LogInformation(_encryption.Encrypt("allentherapy.user"));
            var records = _parse.ParseSubjectCSV("c:\\tmp\\ImportFiles\\Book1.csv");
            if (records.Count > 0)
            {
                SubjectsValidation validator = new SubjectsValidation();

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(record);
                    if (!result.IsValid)
                    {
                        foreach (var failure in result.Errors)
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation($"Failed Validation.  Error: {failure.ErrorMessage}");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                        _insert.InsertUsers(record);

                        //Encrypt the data
                        //save here
                    }
                }
            }
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to re-scope the services, and use a scopeFactory with no success.  I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't think you can use scoped resources for background services. The background service runs on a seperate thread and is not aware of the current scope

Comment: Further readers: you have to do this work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep it simple avoid to inject `IServiceScopeFactory` in the services. The services are already registered as scoped and therefore you can inject `LoginContext` directly in the constuctor. (Which works since `LoginContext` is also a scoped service).

Also `ParseCSVFile` can be registered as singleton as there are no scoped dependencies.

The problem now is that you cannot access the services directly from the singelton `Worker`. This is where `IServiceScopeFactory` does the trick.

The idea is to create (and dispose) a service scope in `ExecuteAsync` like below:

```cs
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Create service scope
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        // Access scoped services like this:
        var insertUser = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IInsertUser>();

        // ....
    }
}
```

As alternative to the approach above you could also refactor all your scoped services to singletons and avoid `IServiceScopeFactory` entirely by using factory interfaces to create short-lived instances.

An example for this is EF Core 5.0's [DbContextFactory<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#dbcontextfactory)

Comment: When I use this method, I keep getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. EDIT: This is fixed, I had to set it to the Interface (IInsertUser) instead of the method.  But now how do I set up the context in the method?

Comment: Sorry for the class vs interface typo. As for the context just add it as constructor parameter, for example `public InsertUser(LoginContext context)` and  it should just work because of the `AddDbContext` call in `ConfigureServices`. Do you get any errors regarding the context?